# .netcore context.Request.EnableRewind() throwing System.IO.Exception once buffer exceeds

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

We have a production deployed application using netcoreapp2.0
We use context.Request.EnableRewind(); to read and log the request before processing.

Since few days intermittently we are getting below unhandled exception in kestrel hosted in AWS Docker ECS.

Basically our request size is more than 30 Kb that's why netcore trying to use filesystem buffer to rewind the request. And it is throwing File is readonly exception.

Is increasing the default buffer limit is the only way  to fix the issue.

```
context.Request.EnableRewind([int bufferthreashold 30720],long? bufferLimit = null]);
```

Or there is any other way to configure request rewind ?
Option to upgrade to 2.1 is not possible for us right now. I see it is fixed in 2.1

```
2019-06-24 14:09:49[41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
[41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
2019-06-24 14:09:49 Connection id "0HLKCN30834Q0", 

Request id "0HLKCN30834Q0:0003B777": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
Connection id "0HLKCN30834Q0", Request id "0HLKCN30834Q0:0003B777": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
2019-06-24 14:09:49System.IO.IOException: Read-only file system
System.IO.IOException: Read-only file system
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by increasing the default buffer size.